# Chosen get selected option custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm filling a JQuery Chosen with values, and I'm setting a custom attribute to get it later when an option is selected, but I can't find a nice way to do it.

My code is the following:

```
$( "#ddlChosen" ).chosen();

for (var i = 0; i < entities.length; i++) {
    $( "#ddlChosen" ).append($('<option>', { value: entities[i].id, 
            text: entities[i].name, uniqueID: entities[i].uniqueID }));
}
```

And what I want is to get the *uniqueID* property. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Using `data-attribute` would be a good idea.

Comment: As @ShaunakD said, you can [add a data attribute](https://api.jquery.com/data/) - `$('<option>', { // ..omitted.. // }).data('uniqueID', entities[i].uniqueID)`

Comment: And when a value is selected, how would I get the uniqueID value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
var options = $( "#ddlChosen option:selected" );

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var property = $(options[i]).attr('uniqueID');

    alert(property);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was it! Meanwhile I'have had found the answer but thanks any way :)